# Firebase setup confusion

Tags: android, firebase

I am following a YouTube tutorial on the topic Firebase. He extended the application class and called `Firebase.setAndroidContext(Context)` in `onCreate`. When I tried to do the same , I couldn't find the class Firebase or the static method `setAndroidContext()`. What am I doing wrong? I followed official guide to setup Firebase in my project.

I got this line is at the bottom of my app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this in project level gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I also copied the needed json file to my project

Comment: Can u post your build.gradle?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: You should be including the necessary Firebase libs in your Gradle file, in this case you need at least core and database. The Firebase docs are pretty good, just make sure you're not looking at the deprecated docs, the ones from after the Mar '16 release are up to date.

Comment: did you add the firebase dependency in the build.gradle file ? check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: What is that dependency mate?

Comment: you need to to add the firebase core dependency `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'`

Answer (score 1):

add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'` in  build.gradle(app)

Works fine if you follow instructions in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

```
No need for 'Firebase.setAndroidContext(Context)' in new sdk.
```

**just follow** https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: I've already done that but still there is no class called Firebase. Is there any chance that the class & method names changed?

Comment: Yaa i think so.. becz in devlepor site they are telling about only two services that is to created .https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1):

In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` so you can remove it from your code.

see the docs here :
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#setting_the_android_context_and_enabling_offline_persistence_numbered